# Checking if domain is active on server

Tags: linux, bash, cpanel, whm

I am trying to check if a domain is active on the server. So far I get errors.

```
list=/root/domainlist.txt
for i in $(cat $list)
do
  echo "checking " $i
  $ip = host $i |grep -o -m 100 '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
  if [[ $ip == "xx.xx.xx.xx" ]]; then
    $i >> /root/activedomains.txt
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
activedomains: line 4: =: command not found
```

This is the current error I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No spaces before and after the `=`
- No dollar sign in the assignment
- You probably want the result of the command, so enclose it in `$(` `)`

  ```
  ip=$(host $i |grep -o -m 100 '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}')
  ```

write to the file like this

```
echo "$i" >> /root/activedomains.txt
```

Comment: didn't see the missing `echo`. +1

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error with the line

```
$ip = host $i |grep -o -m 100 '...'
```

you shoud use instead :

```
ip=$(host $i |grep -o -m 100 '...')
```

---

A better way using *boolean logic* (no need `grep` there, if `host $ip` failed, it will return *FALSE*):

```
list=/root/domainlist.txt

while read ip; do
    echo "checking $ip"
    host "$ip" &>/dev/null && echo "$ip" >> /root/activedomains.txt
done < "$list"
```

It's the equivalent of

```
list=/root/domainlist.txt

while read ip; do
    echo "checking $ip"
    if host "$ip" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$ip" >> /root/activedomains.txt
    fi
done < "$list"
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you shouldn't assign to `$ip` to `ip` ... but it's possible there are more errors.

My guess would be you wanted (line 4/5):

```
ip=$(host $i |grep -o -m 100 '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}')
```

Also read user000001's answer. The missing `echo` when getting the output *is* another issue.